# How do you add a foreign key with Chive?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a former PHPMyAdmin user trying to learn how [Chive](http://www.chive-project.com/) works. Everything is pretty straightforward but I can't figure add how to add foreign keys and there doesn't seem to be much documentation. PHPMyAdmin has a Relation View to add foreign keys but how do I do the same with [Chive](http://www.chive-project.com/)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select your table, browse to the "Structure" tab. You should be able to see "Relation view" link below the fields.

Note: You will only see the "Relation View" if you have a compatible table engine (ie InnoDB)

Comment: Hmm, I changed the table's storage engine to InnoDB in Chive but the "Relation View" is still not an available option.

Comment: @cowmix what version of Chive are you using ? can you add a screenshot of what you have on the structure tab ?

Comment: Chive Version is 1.1
[Structure Image](http://i.imgur.com/kmNot.jpg). I'm able to create the column indexes but I can't figure out how to create their foreign keys

Comment: You get a "Relation View" link in phpMyAdmin. Maybe you mixed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk you through with my example and you can find your way around after this:
I have an InnoDB table, with product_sku column as integer and indexed. Then, with the "Structure" tab of the table being active, if I hover the action icons on the right I will see:

- move - active
- edit - active
- drop - active
- primary key - inactive
- index - inactive
- unique key - active
- fulltext index - inactive
- relation - active or inactive

You are interested in the last one, click on it and an AJAX will load the "Edit relation" form.